# Unexpected end of json input in Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, express, npm

I have Json data which I receive it as post data in my node.js server.

But the problem is, its not able to parse the string I sent.Here is my node.js server code.

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  req.on('data',function(data)
  {
    var done=false;
    console.log(data);
    var schema;

    schema=JSON.parse(data);
   }
```

Here I get the error when I parse the json data(data).

```
undefined:776



SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/as6/Documents/test/server.js:206:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:462:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:833:34)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:815:3)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
```

I verified JSON data using JSONLint for syntax errors.But it was absolutely fine. I dont know what's wrong and how to correct it.

Comment: try to JSON.stringify first and then check whether it is actually in the right format ?
If yes then try this : 
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))

Answer (score 36):

`data` events can be fired *multiple* times, so you have to collect all the `data` values and concatenate them together when the `end` event has fires:

```
let chunks = [];

req.on('data', function(data) {
  chunks.push(data);
}).on('end', function() {
  let data   = Buffer.concat(chunks);
  let schema = JSON.parse(data);
  ...
});
```

However, perhaps you should consider using [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser).

Comment: Thanks a lot.. i its very easy to implement

Comment: @robertklep Hey I tried this solution I am getting an error 
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. Can u please help?

Comment: @mamadgiaishwarya that issue is not strictly related to this question and my answer. If you have could code online somewhere, I'll have a look. Otherwise, search for that error here on SO to find out the cause of it.

Answer (score 8):

Do change the line

```
schema = JSON.parse(data);
```

into

```
schema = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: How would this help?